# "as" and "is" are not applicable to generic type

Tags: generics, delphi-10-seattle

I am surprised that generics are not subject to "is" and "as" operations.

How to implement following?:

```
function TDisplayConfManager._getDisplay<T>(parentCtl: TWinControl; indicatorName: string): T;
var
  i: Integer;
  ind: T;
begin
  for i := 0 to parentCtl.ControlCount-1 do
    if parentCtl.Controls[i] is T then begin // E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
      ind := parentCtl.Controls[i] as T; // E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
      if SameText(ind.Caption, indicatorName) then Exit(ind); // E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Caption'
    end;
  Result := T.Create(_owner); // E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Create'
end;
```

If I use base display class for all my displays, two errors go away, but I can't still use "is" and create an object:

```
function TDisplayConfManager._getDisplay<T>(parentCtl: TWinControl; indicatorName: string): T;
var
  i: Integer;
  ind: TBaseDisplayType;
begin
  for i := 0 to parentCtl.ControlCount-1 do
    if parentCtl.Controls[i] is T then begin // E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
      ind := parentCtl.Controls[i] as TBaseDisplayType;
      if SameText(ind.Caption, indicatorName) then Exit(ind);
    end;
  Result := T.Create(_owner); // E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Create'
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `T` doesn't need to be a class type; it could also be a non-class type, like an integer, a string, a record, or an array.

So the following doesn't compile:

```
type
  TTest<T> = record
    function Test(AObject: TObject): Boolean;
  end;

{ TTest<T> }

function TTest<T>.Test(AObject: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AObject is T; // E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
end;
```

However, if you know that your `T` type will always be a class type, you can express that in Delphi:

```
type
  TTest<T: class> = record
    function Test(AObject: TObject): Boolean;
  end;

{ TTest<T> }

function TTest<T>.Test(AObject: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AObject is T;
end;
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Constraints_in_Generics) contains more details about generic constraints.

*Update in response to comment:*

You can also have constraints at the member level:

```
type
  TTest = record
    function Test<T: class>(AObject: TObject): Boolean;
  end;

{ TTest }

function TTest.Test<T>(AObject: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AObject is T;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the clue. This trick doesn't work with a method. I would like to have a generic method in non-generic class.

Comment: Oh, now it works. I see where my mistake was: I declared it with `<T: class>` in both, interface and implementation. Getting `Caption` still doesn't work, but I'll find the way to do it.